# ExGUtils 3.0 won't install

Tags: python, pip

Hello I am trying to install the ExGUtils 3.0 in my python environment on my VS code on my windows computer. I keep on getting an error which is this:

```
    Collecting ExGUtils
  Using cached ExGUtils-3.0.tar.gz (377 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Leo\Documents\Python setup VSCode\PythonWorkSpace\.venv\Scripts\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Leo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0sbakymg\\exgutils_c5150aa0bfa44ea89ce16af14a8507f3\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Leo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0sbakymg\\exgutils_c5150aa0bfa44ea89ce16af14a8507f3\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-8ujlwys6'
         cwd: C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0sbakymg\exgutils_c5150aa0bfa44ea89ce16af14a8507f3\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0sbakymg\exgutils_c5150aa0bfa44ea89ce16af14a8507f3\setup.py", line 29, in <module>
        bla = raw_input("Compile C [Y/n]? ")
    NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/af/e7/006322dd2e5d3644ac14b1e49c6c77bf1836598eacfb36ef2a96c85b85b3/ExGUtils-3.0.tar.gz#sha256=413cd9f84a8bbff9c1cee1388775a5cd9c7545e6bfb28502d988cf6b2de0515e (from https://pypi.org/simple/exgutils/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached ExGUtils-2.0.tar.gz (873 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: ExGUtils
  Building wheel for ExGUtils (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\Leo\Documents\Python setup VSCode\PythonWorkSpace\.venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Leo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0sbakymg\\exgutils_ed75e0edba84415a97393b42b74dfabb\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Leo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0sbakymg\\exgutils_ed75e0edba84415a97393b42b74dfabb\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-q2fegjyw'
       cwd: C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-0sbakymg\exgutils_ed75e0edba84415a97393b42b74dfabb\
  Complete output (11 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ExGUtils
  copying ExGUtils\pyexg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ExGUtils
  copying ExGUtils\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ExGUtils
  running build_ext
  building 'ExGUtils.uts' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ExGUtils
  Running setup.py clean for ExGUtils
Failed to build ExGUtils
Installing collected packages: ExGUtils
    Running setup.py install for ExGUtils ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Leo\Documents\Python setup VSCode\PythonWorkSpace\.venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Leo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0sbakymg\\exgutils_ed75e0edba84415a97393b42b74dfabb\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Leo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0sbakymg\\exgutils_ed75e0edba84415a97393b42b74dfabb\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-bwzox5tu\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Leo\Documents\Python setup VSCode\PythonWorkSpace\.venv\include\site\python3.9\ExGUtils'
    Complete output (11 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ExGUtils
    copying ExGUtils\pyexg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ExGUtils
    copying ExGUtils\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ExGUtils
    running build_ext
    building 'ExGUtils.uts' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Leo\Documents\Python setup VSCode\PythonWorkSpace\.venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Leo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0sbakymg\\exgutils_ed75e0edba84415a97393b42b74dfabb\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Leo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-0sbakymg\\exgutils_ed75e0edba84415a97393b42b74dfabb\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-bwzox5tu\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Leo\Documents\Python setup VSCode\PythonWorkSpace\.venv\include\site\python3.9\ExGUtils' Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.3; however, version 21.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\Leo\Documents\Python setup VSCode\PythonWorkSpace\.venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
(.venv) PS C:\Users\Leo\Documents\Python setup VSCode\PythonWorkSpace> python -m pip install ExGUtils
Collecting ExGUtils
  Using cached ExGUtils-3.0.tar.gz (377 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Leo\Documents\Python setup VSCode\PythonWorkSpace\.venv\Scripts\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Leo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-da5a3nfv\\exgutils_cea064063ecb48eda3e03df6cf8186f9\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Leo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-da5a3nfv\\exgutils_cea064063ecb48eda3e03df6cf8186f9\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-w1hiuf8f'
         cwd: C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-da5a3nfv\exgutils_cea064063ecb48eda3e03df6cf8186f9\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-da5a3nfv\exgutils_cea064063ecb48eda3e03df6cf8186f9\setup.py", line 29, in <module>
        bla = raw_input("Compile C [Y/n]? ")
    NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/af/e7/006322dd2e5d3644ac14b1e49c6c77bf1836598eacfb36ef2a96c85b85b3/ExGUtils-3.0.tar.gz#sha256=413cd9f84a8bbff9c1cee1388775a5cd9c7545e6bfb28502d988cf6b2de0515e (from https://pypi.org/simple/exgutils/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached ExGUtils-2.0.tar.gz (873 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: ExGUtils
  Building wheel for ExGUtils (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\Leo\Documents\Python setup VSCode\PythonWorkSpace\.venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Leo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-da5a3nfv\\exgutils_15bec1f8cd874388bebb08e44962e7dc\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Leo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-da5a3nfv\\exgutils_15bec1f8cd874388bebb08e44962e7dc\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-7hbbnzp9'
       cwd: C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-da5a3nfv\exgutils_15bec1f8cd874388bebb08e44962e7dc\
  Complete output (11 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ExGUtils
  copying ExGUtils\pyexg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ExGUtils
  copying ExGUtils\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ExGUtils
  running build_ext
  building 'ExGUtils.uts' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ExGUtils
  Running setup.py clean for ExGUtils
Failed to build ExGUtils
Installing collected packages: ExGUtils
    Running setup.py install for ExGUtils ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Leo\Documents\Python setup VSCode\PythonWorkSpace\.venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Leo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-da5a3nfv\\exgutils_15bec1f8cd874388bebb08e44962e7dc\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Leo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-da5a3nfv\\exgutils_15bec1f8cd874388bebb08e44962e7dc\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-9piz1prw\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Leo\Documents\Python setup VSCode\PythonWorkSpace\.venv\include\site\python3.9\ExGUtils'
         cwd: C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-da5a3nfv\exgutils_15bec1f8cd874388bebb08e44962e7dc\
    Complete output (11 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ExGUtils
    copying ExGUtils\pyexg.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ExGUtils
    copying ExGUtils\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\ExGUtils
    running build_ext
    building 'ExGUtils.uts' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Leo\Documents\Python setup VSCode\PythonWorkSpace\.venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Leo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-da5a3nfv\\exgutils_15bec1f8cd874388bebb08e44962e7dc\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Leo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-da5a3nfv\\exgutils_15bec1f8cd874388bebb08e44962e7dc\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-9piz1prw\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Leo\Documents\Python setup VSCode\PythonWorkSpace\.venv\include\site\python3.9\ExGUtils' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I know the problem is that I am using python 3 where `raw_input` is now `input`, I am not sure how to fix this problem and would like any help I can get. The only solution I can think of is creating a new environment for Python 2, is there any other way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As you have already noted, the package seems to have been written with python 2x in mind. Since this library is quite small, you can simply download the [source code](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/af/e7/006322dd2e5d3644ac14b1e49c6c77bf1836598eacfb36ef2a96c85b85b3/ExGUtils-3.0.tar.gz) from pypi, extract it and edit the line in the setup.py:

```
bla = raw_input("Compile C [Y/n]? ")
```

to make it python3 compatible. Then run `python setup.py install` in the source code folder.

Note though that you have an additional error:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

In case you want to install the C backend of this library (optional), you will need to make sure that you install that.

Comment: So I replaced `bla = raw_input("Compile C [Y/n]? ")`  to  `bla = input("Compile C [Y/n]? ")` and I downloaded an installed the  Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 package; and created a new '.tar' with the modified file. How do I install this modified version?

I have also placed the modified.tar into my python environment folder.

Comment: So I tried putting the modified folder in the environment and ran it, the only thing that happened was a input dialog which I typed y and nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

FWIW: I skipped the input dialog by commenting it out and adding:

```
bla = "Y"
```

I tried to install it, but my clang compiler puked on it's C-code.

```
ExGUtils/csources/_Uts.c:208:11: error: call to undeclared function 'Py_InitModule3'; ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

Had to do this to "_uts.c" to get it to work

```
/* Deprecated
PyMODINIT_FUNC inituts(void) {
    PyObject* mod;
    // Create the module
    mod = Py_InitModule3("uts", module_methods, utils_docstring);
    if (mod == NULL) {
       return;
    }
}
*/
static struct PyModuleDef Combinations =
{
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "uts",                          /* name of module */
    utils_docstring,                /* module documentation, may be NULL */
    -1,                         /* size of per-interpreter state of the module, or -1 if the module keeps state in global variables. */
    module_methods
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_Combinations(void)
{
    return PyModule_Create(&Combinations);
}
```